# Swiftui how to update variable once view is closed

Tags: swiftui

I am using SwiftUi 3.0 and I am new to it . I am learning about ObservedObjects . What I am trying to do is update the count of a variable every time that I close a view . This is the entire small app . The screen starts at **DataUpdateView** view when I click Next View I go to **DataUpdateView2** view . Once I close **DataUpdateView2** and go back to the original view I want to have the

```
 Text("Score Count \(progress.score)")
```

score number increase by 1 since in the second view I do a +1 every time that I close that view . Any suggestions would be great

```
import SwiftUI


class UserProgress: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score = 0
}

struct DataUpdateView: View {
    @State var nextView = false
    @StateObject var progress = UserProgress()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Text("Score Count \(progress.score)")
            Text("Next View")
                .onTapGesture {
                    nextView = true
                }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $nextView, content: {
                   DataUpdateView2()
                })
        }
        
    }
}

struct DataUpdateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DataUpdateView()
    }
}


struct DataUpdateView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var progress = UserProgress()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Text("Back")
            .onTapGesture {
                progress.score += 1
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            
    }
}

struct DataUpdateView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DataUpdateView2()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not seeing the first view update since both views are instantiating their own `UserProgress()`. You need to pass the object you already created in the first view along to the second in the initializer
So In `DataUpdateView`:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $nextView, content: {
       DataUpdateView2(progress: progress)
   })
}
```

And then in `DataUpdateView2`:

```
struct DataUpdateView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var progress: UserProgress
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    // ...
}
```

So now the second view is receiving the object from the first rather than creating its own.

Answer (score 1):

Note: If you are not using an `ObservableObject`, then take a look at the second part.

In this specific situation, you don't even need a `Binding` variable, you can just use the `.onDisappear` method. [`.onDisappear` Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/ondisappear(perform:)).

```swift
import SwiftUI


class UserProgress: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score = 0
}

struct DataUpdateView: View {
    @State var nextView = false
    @StateObject var progress = UserProgress()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Text("Score Count \(progress.score)")
            Text("Next View")
                .onTapGesture {
                    nextView = true
                }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $nextView, content: {
                   DataUpdateView2()
                })
        }
        
    }
}

struct DataUpdateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DataUpdateView()
    }
}


struct DataUpdateView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var progress = UserProgress()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Text("Back")
.onTapGesture{
presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
print("Dismissed!")
}
           .onDisappear{
//This is called when the view disappears.
progress.score += 1
}
            
    }
}

struct DataUpdateView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DataUpdateView2()
    }
}
```

**Second Part**
If you want the variable to update when the view closes, you could use the `.onDisappear` method and a `Binding` value. An example implementation of this is below:

```swift
struct ViewOne: View{
@State var number = 0
var body: some View{
VStack{
Text("Number: \(number)")
NavigationLink(destination: ViewTwo(variable: $number)){
Text("Go To View Two")
}
}
}

}

struct ViewTwo: View{
@Binding var variable: Int

var body: some View{
//Content of view 2 here
Text("View Two")
.onDisappear{
//This is called when the view disappears
variable += 1
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short you need to use same view model in both views. A possible and seems simplest approach in your code is to inject view model from first view to second via environment object, like

```
@StateObject var progress = UserProgress()
var body: some View {
    VStack {
    Text("Score Count \(progress.score)")
        Text("Next View")
            .onTapGesture {
                nextView = true
            }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $nextView, content: {
               DataUpdateView2()
                 .environmentObject(progress)    // << here !!
            })
```

and use it internally, like

```
struct DataUpdateView2: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var progress: UserProgress  // << injected automatically !!
```